# On click, loop through each object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I'm still learning JS and something is harder to understand than others.

Like so:

I am trying to change the theme of google maps by allowing users to click on a custom button.

I was using if else which works great but i wanted to add more themes and using a loop. Each time a user clicks, it selects:

```
object key 0, 
then click again object key 2 
and object key 3 
and repeat
```

I can get the object keys and values how I'm lost after that.

- This is the theme object

  let theme = {
    default: null,
    night: [multiple objects with nested arrays],
    dark: [multiple objects with nested arrays]
  }
- creating button inside google maps then addEventListener

  let themeToggle = document.createElement('button');
    themeToggle.classList.add('controlUI');
    themeToggle.innerHTML = ('Mode');
    themeToggle.title = 'Change map theme';

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(themeToggle);

  let mode = true;
    themeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (mode) {
        map.setOptions({styles: theme.night});
      } else {
        map.setOptions({styles: theme.default});
      }
      mode = !mode;
    });

Above Works Fine

Im struggling to convert the if else to a loop and select each object key and then adding that to:

```
map.setOptions({styles: theme.night})
```

and then on click it loops through each key and repeat

```
themeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    for ( let key  in theme) {
      map.setOptions({styles: theme[key]});
      console.log(theme[key])
    }
  });
```

it selects the last one by default and i cant toggle.

Any help would e really appreciated, just trying add all the puzzle together.

Comment: Object keys are unordered, so this is in no way reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collect the object values into an array, then increment an index with modulo on every click:

```
const vals = Object.values(theme);
let i = 0;
themeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  map.setOptions({styles: vals[i]});
  i = (i + 1) % vals.length;
});
```

While most environments will result in an object's `Object.values` in ascending numeric followed by insertion order, it's not guaranteed. If you need a guaranteed predictable ordering, use `Reflect.ownKeys` (or `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`) instead:

```
const vals = Reflect.ownKeys(theme)
  .map(key => theme[key]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. After doing testing and using console log , it really helped me understand how that is working. :D

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through an object like this

```js
var invoice = {
  name: 'anik',
  age: 29,
  designation: 'Full Stack Developer'
}

Object.keys(invoice).map((d,i)=>{                 
  console.log(d +' : '+invoice[d]);
})
```